# LICR representation with UTF-8

Tags: input-encodings

A way to get the LICR representation of a string (in `pdflatex`) is with `\protected@edef`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\protected@edef\result{^^f6}
\show\result

\end{document}
```

prints

```
> \result=macro:
->\"o.
```

So far so good.

Formerly, this used to work if the encoding was `utf8`. With TL2018:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\protected@edef\result{^^c3^^b6} % ie, ^^f6 in UTF-8 encoding
\show\result

\end{document}
```

the following was shown:

```
> \result=macro:
->\IeC {\"o}.
```

But I’ve just realized it no longer works, because now it returns the actual character:

```
> \result=macro:
->ö.
```

This means the resulting string can’t be manipulated in an encoding independent way. The reason for this change in behavior is the characters are now `\protected` (an eTeX primitive), thus preventing the expansion to their internal definition, aka LICR.

- Is there a way to make them un-`\protected` without redefining the
  characters every time a LICR is to be generated?
- Or more in general, is there an alternative way to generate the LICR
  representation with `utf8`, as with `cp1252`, `applemac` and other
  8-bit encodings.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ' string can’t be manipulated in an encoding independent way': the idea is that everything converts to UTF-8, and then internally you always use that.

Comment: @JosephWright But this is not what 8-bit encodings are doing.

Comment: Sure, you always cover the UTF-8 and macro version, as even in UTF-8 the user might have `\"o` or `ö`, and that difference should be retained as far as possible.

Comment: @JosephWright The macro will print a wrong result after a `\inputencoding{cp1252}`. Well, admittedly this is a quite infrequent situation, but formerly it worked.

Comment: Something similar was discussed on the team list when we made the change: you can't for example 'know' the right answer for `\def\foo{ö}\inputencoding{cp1252}\protected@edef\foo{\foo}`. So the conclusion was that it's not feasible to make the change (needed for other reasons) and keep 100% the same behaviour.

Comment: Could you give the wider context there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `\getlicr` in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\getlicr}{mm}{%
  \cs_set_eq:Nc #1 { u8:\tl_to_str:n {#2} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\getlicr{\result}{^^c3^^b6}
\show\result

\getlicr{\result}{ö}
\show\result

\stop
```

Console output:

```
> \result=macro:
->\IeC {\"o}.
l.10 \show\result

?
> \result=macro:
->\IeC {\"o}.
l.13 \show\result
```

With some stretches…

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\getlicr}{mm}
 {
  \javier_getlicr:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \g__javier_licr_item_tl
\seq_new:N \l__javier_licr_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__javier_licr_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \javier_getlicr:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__javier_licr_in_seq { ~ } { #2 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__javier_licr_out_seq
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__javier_licr_in_seq \__javier_licr:n
  \tl_set:Ne #1 { \seq_use:Nn \l__javier_licr_out_seq { ~ } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__javier_licr:n
 {
  \tl_gclear:N \g__javier_licr_item_tl
  \text_map_function:nN { #1 } \__javier_licr_item:n
  \group_begin:
    \cs_set:Npn \IeC ##1 { \exp_not:n { ##1 } }
    \tl_gset:Ne \g__javier_licr_item_tl { \g__javier_licr_item_tl }
  \group_end:
  \seq_put_right:NV \l__javier_licr_out_seq \g__javier_licr_item_tl
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__javier_licr_item:n 
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g__javier_licr_item_tl {#1}
   }
   {
    \tl_gput_right:Nv \g__javier_licr_item_tl { u8:\tl_to_str:n {#1} }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getlicr{\result}{^^c3^^b6}
\texttt{\meaning\result} $\to$ \result

\getlicr{\result}{eäñçîw xyž}
\texttt{\meaning\result} $\to$ \result

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, and upvoted, but it converts just a character, not a string.

Comment: @JavierBezos I was adding it…

Comment: Fails if there is space, but anyway you have put me on the right track, so I’ll accept it.

Comment: @JavierBezos Reworked for spaces

Answer (score 4):

You aren't supposed to need this:-) but...

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
{
  \def\IeC#1{\unexpanded{\IeC{#1}}}
\expandafter
\edef
\expandafter
\result
\expandafter
{^^c3^^b6} % ie, ^^f6 in UTF-8 encoding
\show\result
}

\stop
```

produces

```
> \result=macro:
->\IeC {\"o}.
l.18 \show\result
```

Comment: Yes, I knew the `\expandafter` trick (when I discovered I was perplexed), but sadly it only works for the first character.

Comment: @JavierBezos well yes etex `\protected` has many benefits over latex `\protect` but the one disadvantage is that it's a lot harder to locally undo. The l3 text module will probably do what you want (it knows how to decompose these definitions) but it depends what you really want

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are after `\text_purify:n`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\expander\text_purify:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\edef\result{\expander{^^f6}}
\show\result

\end{document}
```

This should give a UTF-8 representation as far as possible for most input encodings (at some stage it likely needs extending to cover all of at least PU).